# Genome assembly from error-prone reads

Tags: genome, assembly, reads

I understand how to assemble genome from error-free reads. I implemented like this:

> Construct directed overlap graph with reads as vertices and edges as
>   maximum overlap between two vertices. Edges represent the length of
>   overlapping maximum substring of one read suffix with other read
>   prefix. Find the path that visits all vertices only once in overlap
>   graph. With small graph we can use greedy approach : Starting from
>   first pattern always choose egde of maximum weight and store shortest
>   common superstring spelled by this path in resulting string. Resulting
>   string spelled by path is shortest common superstring of all reads,
>   that is assembled genome.

For example

```
AACTAG
  CTAGAT
```

Gives the `AACTAGAT` as a result

Now let's say that two error-prone reads have at most one error (mismatch):

```
AACTAG
  CTCGAT
```

As you can see second read has one substitution in third character from **'A'** to **'C'**.

So how assembled genome should look like for the error-prone reads? Do I take **A** or **C** to resulting string? Or I'm missing something?

Note: I used short reads for example because of simplicity. I work with much larger number of reads which are 100 nucleotides long and have at most one substitution of character. So that's a big overlap graph. I know I can use De Bruijn graph, but can I use some greedy approach (like in error-free example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common for assemblers to have a coverage threshold to make sure that there are enough reads across the same region to properly assemble a contig.

You can't work out an ideal solution from a situation where the consensus sequence is ambiguous. If your overlap were representative (e.g. a heterozygous variant in a diploid genome, based on a few tens of reads of 100bp, rather than 6bp), then the resulting assembly would have a bubble in the assembly graph at the variant point.

```
        A
       / \
A-A-C-T   G-A-T
       \ /
        C
```

A conservative assembler might produce two assembled contigs corresponding to these two paths, AACTAGAT and AACTCGAT. A greedy assembler would just pick one path and use that. Subsequent assembly steps might attempt to search for bubbles and annotate the assembled contigs with variant locations.

Comment: For all mainstream short-read overlappers, if there is a mismatch, the overlap will be missed entirely. You don't get a bubble. Usually you need at least 4 reads to see a bubble and the bubble is not single-based in string/overlap graph.

Comment: Yes, for the particular example that was given, a bubble wouldn't be formed. I was assuming that the reads were representative of something with a better coverage (e.g. overlap of 50 long sequences, with half having a variant, and half not)

Answer (score 2):

For short reads, the typical and the most widely used solution is to correct away sequencing errors before assembly. You can correct errors with k-mer spectrum, a trie or multi-alignment. There are many papers on this topic.

Error correction alone won't fix all sequencing errors. Remaining errors may lead to bubbles and tips in the overlap/de Bruijn graph. You can identify them by inspecting the local topology of assembly graph.

Comment: So what would be solution from error-prone sample above?

Comment: No solution to your example. You can only identify errors with sufficient coverage.